# Need a faster method to concatenate rows into column(s)--currently using CTEs

Tags: cte, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently, we are using a view which I created that pulls data from a number of tables.  The major factor about this is getting the view to specifications involves a mix of CTEs and string concatenating to combine multiple rows into one column (multiple times).
While the view works, users have recently complained about it being too slow.
Currently, the view setup looks something like this:

```
;
With thing1 AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
            /* huge block of code with joins and such  
            that gets the individual fields and concatenates  
            personnel names to one row */
)
,
thing2 AS
(
    SELECT  TaskName,
            Company,
            Lease,
            TaskBegin,
            TaskEnd,
            Field,
            Personnel,
            Invoice,
            InvDate,
            InvTot,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by TaskName ORDER BY [TaskName] ASC) rn
    FROM thing1 
)

SELECT  TaskName,
        Company,
        Lease,
        Field,
        ISNULL(Personnel, '') as 'Personnel',
        TaskBegin,
        TaskEnd,
        ISNULL (STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + Invoice 
                FROM thing1
                WHERE (thing1.TaskName = thing2.TaskName)
                AND thing2.rn = 1
                ORDER BY Invoice
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS 'Invoice',
        ISNULL (STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + InvDate 
                FROM thing1
                WHERE (thing1.TaskName = thing2.TaskName)
                AND thing2.rn = 1
                ORDER BY Invoice
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS 'InvoiceDate',
        ISNULL (STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + InvTot 
                FROM thing1
                WHERE (thing1.TaskName = thing2.TaskName)
                AND thing2.rn = 1
                ORDER BY Invoice
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS 'InvoiceTotal'
    FROM thing2 WHERE rn = 1

GO
```

So it works as intended.  Problem is, once I get to that final SELECT that concatenates the Invoice, InvDate, and InvTot, the query goes from not needing a single second (that is, a straight SELECT from thing2) to taking up to 7 seconds to run its course.  (Average time is about 5 seconds.)  I'm fairly confident that part of the blame lies in the ever-growing database--this view loads much faster on the test environment, which has far fewer records in it.

My question is thus:  **Is it possible to go about this in a way that is faster and less resource-intensive on the DB?**

Comment: Are you sure you know exactly where the problem is? Have you looked at an actual (not estimated) execution plan?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue in your code is multiple access to the CTEs and all the complicated logic you have in there. You should try to do everyting in a single pass with UNPIVOT/PIVOT. I did something similar here:
http://spaghettidba.com/2011/10/13/concatenating-multiple-columns-across-rows/

In my example you will find the concatenation of sentences in different languages (not exactly what you're after), but it seems to me that you could use the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you have is an EAV pattern (so that block of code is mostly joins to the same take) that you need to transpose for reporting. If that is the case then you might find the `PIVOT` feature can make those CTEs more efficient (both in code readability and execution run time): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that `FOR XML PATH` is the culprit that slows down the view, you can use a different approach to concatenate rows into a single column. This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6353c/1) demonstrate how to use a recursive CTE for concatenation.

Just insert cte1, cte2, cte2 and cte4 between your thing1 and thing2, and then just use the Invoice, Invdate, InvTot columns from cte4 directly in place of your last three columns (where you use FOR XML PATH)